# Android M: Effect of Selective Permissions on Ads

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Now that Android 6.0 becomes more popular among users, I've asked myself what the consequences of the selective permission granting are.

Let's assume I had a free ad-supported version of an app. It will obviously need internet permission to query ads. Now the user is able to deny that permission and apps could not be queried. The consequence I am thinking of is to deny app function if not all the permissions are granted. But this would make the permission model pointless for my app. It would be an "all or nothing" scenario. Is that thinking correct? I am interested in your thoughts.

Another thought I had was: Is the permission of internet access granted to AdMob automatically, by any chance? This would prevent users from disablings ads simply by takingvaway the internet permission. As AdMob is a Google company and this functionality is implemented in the Google Play Services, I guess that could be possible?! Any thoughts on this?

Let me know what you think.

**Update: Admob also wants to have Location Info. So even though Internet does not need permission, the question still is interesting.**

Answer (score 1):

@mad: in android 6.0, your app never ask your to allow internet permission. because internet not part of user's privacy in android 6.0

(***in sort user not able to deny internet permission***) only on/off internet from device!

***so don't worry about it. you app work same in android 6.0 as previous version of android.***

you have to ask user for permission only if you are using, CAMERA, CONTACTS, LOCATION, MICROPHONE, Phone, STORAGE ...etc..

---

LOCATION: when you fetch location from your app and pass to any 3rd party app. in this case you must have to ask user to allow location permission. otherwise its not needed like Google Play service or In-App Purchease.(both fetch user location where app installed or product purchase but when we use both library in our app we must not have to ask location permission).